# Serve a 404 page with app created with Vue-CLI

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, http-status-code-404, vue-cli

I'm using Vue-CLI to create Vue apps. One behaviour I don't like is that any non-existing URL (eg, `localhost:8080/nonexistent/file.html`) gets served, with code 200, as if it was the root: `localhost:8080`.

This makes debugging XHR requests really messy sometimes.

How can I make it return a 404 code?

Comment: are you using vue-router?

Comment: No, just the standard stuff that comes with a default `vue create`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The feature you're observing is actually from [`webpack-dev-server`'s `historyApiFallback`](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserver-historyapifallback), which responds with `index.html` for unresolved URLs (intended for SPAs with client-side routing). This is enabled by default in Vue CLI projects, but you can disable it with a Vue CLI [`devServer` config](https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#devserver):

1. Create `vue.config.js` (if it doesn't exist already) with the following contents:

   ```
   module.exports = {
     devServer: {
       historyApiFallback: false
     }
   }
   ```
2. Restart your dev server (`npm run serve`).