# React.js (Vite) application returns 404 on return in monorepository

Tags: reactjs, vite, vercel, netlify, turborepo

###### Nevermind...

Mistake was related to the codebase (where I'm using `monorepo` and `vercel.json` was on the root directory. After moving `vercel.js` to package with `react` application everything was working perfectly.

---

#### The 404 Problem

I have a simple `React.js` application with `wouter`-based routing and `Vercel` deployments that drive me into a little issue where I have no idea about the solution. It always returns `404` after refresh (of subpage).

My code looks a bit like this.

```
    <>
        <Route path='/' component={Intro} />
        <Route path='/dashboard' component={Dashboard} />
    </>
```

Where on `<Intro />` I have `<Link />` to `/dashboard` which should transfer me to `<Dashboard />` page. And it does work on my local machine, in a container, and on Linux-based deployment, but it doesn't really work in `vercel` deployment, even if I tried to resolve this issue with the configuration of `vercel.json`.

```json
{
    "github": {
        "silent": true
    },
    "rewrites": [
        {
            "source": "(.*)",
            "destination": "/index.html"
        }
    ]
}
```

Also tried an alternative version of `rewrites` and still the same issue.

```json
{
  "rewrites": [{ "source": "/(.*)", "destination": "/" }]
}
```

Link to live deployment available here: pointrest-6ttd9zep8-araclx.vercel.app

> NOTE: I was also trying to use `react-router` but the same problem exists. Same problem exist when application is hosted on `netlify` but doesn't exist at all when hosted on `heroku` or run inside `docker` container.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69701743/how-can-i-configure-vites-dev-server-to-give-404-errors The solution has ben soved in this Question!

Comment: Not exactly, I was not aware of that `vercel` can have a problems with monorepo structure. Question you provided is on completely different topic.

Answer (score 14):

You can a create simple rewrites rules in the serve. In my case I use Vercel. Then you can find something similar this.

Create in the project root a file vercel.json

And writer

```
{
  "rewrites": [{ "source": "/(.*)", "destination": "/" }]
}
```

P.S.: Don't forget to enable rewrites in vercel.

Comment: Mate you're wrong, You cannot put `vercel.json` in Project Root, because if you're using monorepo structure this will not work. It's supposed to be in **Application Directory (with package.json)**.

Comment: yea as @keinsell said, I put `vercel.json` in my application directory (mine is called `/client`) and it worked :)

Comment: Sorry! I meant. Exactly next to the package.json.

Answer (score 1):

TLDR

Add an empty 404.html in the **public** folder (you can put the title in the title tag) with this script in the head section

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var pathSegmentsToKeep = 0;

  var l = window.location;
  l.replace(
    l.protocol + '//' + l.hostname + (l.port ? ':' + l.port : '') +
    l.pathname.split('/').slice(0, 1 + pathSegmentsToKeep).join('/') + '/?/' +
    l.pathname.slice(1).split('/').slice(pathSegmentsToKeep).join('/').replace(/&/g, '~and~') +
    (l.search ? '&' + l.search.slice(1).replace(/&/g, '~and~') : '') +
    l.hash
  );
    </script>
```

Then add this script to your index.html

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  (function(l) {
    if (l.search[1] === '/' ) {
      var decoded = l.search.slice(1).split('&').map(function(s) { 
        return s.replace(/~and~/g, '&')
      }).join('?');
      window.history.replaceState(null, null,
          l.pathname.slice(0, -1) + decoded + l.hash
      );
    }
  }(window.location))
    </script>
```

This worked perfectly for me after deploying my app to render.com

To handle the "real" not found response, you can add this route

```
<Route path="*" element={<p>Page not found</p>} />
```

For more information you can visit this repo [spa-github-pages](https://github.com/rafgraph/spa-github-pages)

Credits to [@rafgraph](https://github.com/rafgraph)